# Underscore: comparing mongoose objectIds failing

Tags: mongoose, underscore.js

I am having trouble comparing mongoose ObjectId's or their String values.

I have two arrays, the first is:

```
a = [
"50dfb24123c43a501400000e",
"50d1bda330eb531c1400000d",
"50d1bdcf30eb531c1400000f",
"50d1beac30eb531c14000012",
"50dfb26223c43a501400000f"
]
```

and the second is:

```
b = [
"50dfb26223c43a501400000f"
]
```

running `_.intersection(a,b)` gives me an empty array `[]` instead of the value in `b`.

The values of a and b are `_.pluck`ed from results returned by a Mongoose model.
I have tried converting each of the array values to strings, and I still get the same result of an empty array.

I searched for similar questions, but the solutions that I've found aren't helping (i.e. the conversion to strings).

Is there something I am missing? I know that the problem is the Mongoose ObjectIds because if I intersect the raw arrays as pasted above, I get the correct result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `_.intersection` with arrays of `ObjectId`s in this case because `intersection` uses simple reference equality to compare the elements, rather than comparing their contents.  To compare two `ObjectId`s for equality you need to use the `ObjectId.equals` method.

So the simplest solution would be to convert the arrays to strings so that `intersection` will work.  I know you said you tried that, but you probably had a bug somewhere as that does work.

Comment: I ended up getting the string conversion right. I also now use ObjectId(var), which seems simpler and is working. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In lodash4, you can now do this:

```
_.intersectionWith(a, b, _.isEqual)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use _.isEqual(object, other) to test if 2 mongoose ObjectID are have same content.

for instance,

```
var ret=[];
_.each(b,function(x){
    ret.push(_.filter(a,function(y){
        return _.isEqual(x,y);
    }))
})
```

now, you should get ret contains "50dfb26223c43a501400000f" as data type of Mongoose's ObjectId.